# Are Java Strings supposed to be converted to a python unicode when added to a Collection

Tags: jython, jython-2.7

I'm seeing the following behavior with jython 2.7.0:

```
>>> from java.lang import String
>>> from java.util import ArrayList
>>> a = String("hello")
>>> b = ArrayList()
>>> b.add(a)
True
>>> a == b.get(0)
False
>>> type(a)
<type 'java.lang.String'>
>>> type(b.get(0))
<type 'unicode'>
```

I'd expect that any java `Object` added to a java `List` in jython would be preserved as is. I tried googling and searching the jython docs, but I couldn't find anything about this behavior.

Comment: Whoa, look at that.  Also observed on jython2.7b3.

Comment: On https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonDeveloperGuide/UsingPyNewStringFromPythonCode, it says "Since Jython automatically converts Java Strings to Python unicode objects...":

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be a pretty obscure spot to put what seems like a pretty significant language behavior. And it only seems to be in reference to getting unicode vs byte strings, not the deeper issue of automatic conversion. Also, it doesn't always convert `String`s to `unicode`. The `a` variable is still a `java.lang.String`. It's only when adding it to the list does it get converted.